# Ruby path makes require impossible

Tags: ruby, rack, require, ruby-grape

I am a beginner in ruby, and i have a problem using my ruby script, that work on my computer, on a server.

My problem is that i don't become to `require 'rack/cors'` and `require 'grape'`

On my computer it works, without using any trick. But on the server ruby is installed on home directory.
I became to require cors using `require '../ruby/gems/gems/rack-cors-0.2.7/lib/rack/cors'`, but it feels like it's dirty so i would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

I did not became to use `RUBYLIB` env variable or -I of ruby.

My final goal is to use rack, so using rackup to launch my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/), none of this would be an issue.

It allows you to install gems into arbitrary locations, but more importantly, loads them from whatever location you've installed them in automatically.

Answer (score 1):

By adding new dir into `$LOAD_PATH`

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift YOUR_RACK_PATH unless $LOAD_PATH.include? YOUR_RACK_PATH
```

Comment: But this is only for one lib, i would like to know if there is a way to make ruby understand this is the path you must follow to find libs.